# Perl: Script reads in a list of sequence names from one file and find associated sequence from another file not worked

Tags: perl, file

I want to find the the information listed in file.txt from file.tbl. The file details and the script are as follows.

The file.txt is formatted as:

```
#comp120_c2_seq3                                                       918   0.0  
# comp120_c2_seq1                                                       918   0.0  
 #comp21106_c0_seq1                                                     874   0.0  
 #comp120_c2_seq2                                                       835   0.0
```

while the file.tbl is formatted as:

```
#comp788_c0_seq1_ CCTAATCATTTAATGTTTTTTT

#comp1107_c0_seq1_ CAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTGTCA

#comp1570_c0_seq3_ TTTTTTTTCTTTTAACAAC

#......
```

My script is as:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w

#This script reads in a list of sequence names from one file and find associated sequence from another file

 open(NAME,"<$ARGV[0]")||die;
 open(SEQ,"<$ARGV[1]")||die;
 $name = "";
 $seq = "";
 %pair = ();

while(<SEQ>){
 s/\cM/\n/g;
        s/\r\n/\n/g;
        s/\r/\n/g; 
  @line = split("\t",$_);
  $name = $line[0];
  $name =~s/\_+/\_/g;
  if ($name=~/^(comp\S*)\_(seq)/){
   $name = $1;
  }
  $seq = $line[1];
  $pair{$name} = $seq;
 }

while (<NAME>){
  s/\cM/\n/g;
         s/\r\n/\n/g;
         s/\r/\n/g;
  if (/^(comp\S*)\s+(seq)/){
          print ">$1\n$pair{$1}";
  }

}

close NAME;
close SEQ;
```

Help me on this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please format your post to make it readable.

Comment: thanks for simbabque for the formated, but I do not know how to format the post online. the file do not include "#" for each line.

Comment: when I do my script, I can find nothing in the out file, what is wrong with my script?

Comment: @fish For help with formatting, see [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume the file.tbl as a FASTA file?

If so, you can use `Bio::SeqIO;` to read the file instead.

```
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $in = Bio::SeqIO->new('-file' => "file.tbl", 
                         '-format' => 'fasta');

while (my $seq = $in->next_seq()) {
    # save $seq into a hash
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Chu Ya'an Xiaonan. the file.tbl as a table file

Comment: @fish So sorry about that, I supposed it as a fasta file because I saw many ATCGs which are symbols of DNA base pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `/^(comp\S*)\s+(seq)/` in the `while (<NAME>)` loop doesn't match a sequence name, since there is no space `\s` before the `seq…` part, but an underscore `_`; the pattern here should be exactly the same as in the `while(<SEQ>)` loop.